# Compass Rails 3.0 working with 'compass watch' but not without

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass

I'm trying Compass with Rails 3.0.7, just trying to get started. Using gem compass-rails. If I put my sass file in app/assets/stylesheets and run 'compass watch', everything works ok: the compiled css is put into public/stylesheets.

However, if I stop 'watch' and rely on Rails to do the compilation, it does not work. Instead, the program looks at the public/stylesheets/sass folder for the input. Furthermore, if a file in that folder has the '@include "compass"' directive, I get an error that the file is not found. How do I force Rails to look in the right place -- app/assets/stylesheets?

Comment: I have tried putting "sass_dir = 'app/assets/stylesheets'" into config/compass.rb, but it does not help.

Comment: Do you use the assets pipelining?